# How many groups of order $n$ with center {e} exist?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> For which numbers $n$ exists a group of order $n$ with center {e} ?
>   And how many groups are there for a given order ?

The first such numbers are $6,10,12,14,18,20,21,...$ Groups of order $32,40,64$,
for example have not center {e}. For $n=18$, we have $2$ groups with center {e}

Is there an easy criterion or formula ?

Comment: An interesting question might be whether there is an upper bound on the number of centreless groups of order $n$ that is asymptotically better than a bound of the form $n^{c \log(n)^2}$, which holds for the total number of groups of order $n$ with $c=2/27$. I am not certain about this, but I am very confident that the answer is no, and there exists a $c$ such that there exist that number of centreless groups for arbitrarily large $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no general criterion or a formula known, especially for finding the number of groups with trivial center.

But there are plenty of examples of families of such numbers $n$. For example $n$ order of any nonabelian simple group, $n = pq$ with $p > q$ primes such that $q \nmid p-1$, etc..

Furthermore, if $G$ and $H$ have trivial center, then so does $G \times H$. Thus the set of such numbers $n$ is closed under multiplication.

Also note that if a group is nilpotent, then it has nontrivial center. There is a simple description of integers $n$ (in terms of prime factorization) such that every group of order $n$ is nilpotent. Hence if there is a group of of order $n$ with trivial center, then $n$ cannot be of this form.

However, there do exist numbers $n$ such that every group of order $n$ has nontrivial center, but not all groups of order $n$ are nilpotent. Some examples are $n = 28, 40, 44, 63, 76, 88, 92, \cdots$ ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/A216594)) Describing numbers like this does not seem feasible to me.